# Front View background transparent

Tags: android, android-layout

I add a View in front of a textView. But I want I can see the text through my View. 
Like this: [image]

Thank in advance, any answers are appreciate :D

Comment: If you mean you don't want to see it...Have you tried setting the background of your new view to an opaque color? android:background="#FFDDDDDD" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a tranparent dialog by this.

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle(" ");
        alertDialog.setMessage("");
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
        alertDialog.setButton("Accept", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setButton2("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

After this just put a line in AndroidManifest.xml, where you define your activity in manifest.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Try below code

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Comment: This is OK, but how can I change "black semitransparent" to "white semitransparent"? or other color? I want to make it like the screen above..

Comment: you can create a xml file as required and set it to alert dialog as alertDialog.setView(your_xml_file);

Answer (score 3):

In XML layout, make your background semitransparent. If it's a simple view add this to your main layout:

```
android:background="#80FFFFFF"
```

Comment: Thanks but which tab is semitransparent in XML file? In case my background is 9 patch image? can I make it semitransparent?

Comment: add the bacground attr to the root layout

Comment: You will have to edit your 9-patch.. But 9-patch is not required.. just set your view ackground as i suggested.. it will do..